# Processing multiple arrays into multiple csv's

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I am a beginner trying to run a for loop over multiple arrays independently and output the results to multiple csv files. However, I cannot seem to figure it out logically. For a,b,c input arrays I want to output a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2 arrays. A shortened version of my code is as such:

```
#get all elements of array:
a[:]
b[:]
c[:]
w8[:]
for i in ([a],[b],[c]):

#multiply values with weighting:
    w = np.zeros((27,72))
    w = np.multiply(i,w8)

#sum columns and rows:
    suma0 = np.sum(w,axis=0)
    suma1 = np.sum(w,axis=1)

#find the minimum values for rows and columns:
    col_min=np.min(w)
    col_min0=a.min(0)
    row_min=np.min(w[:,27])
    row_min0=a.min(1)

#Save as csv with pandas:
    col_min0.to_csv('out1.csv', sep=',')
    row_min0.to_csv('out2.csv', sep=',')
```

Any help would be much appreciated.